# Is it wrong to create semantic SQL tables that do not differ in the type of data contained?

Tags: sql, database-design

For argument sake, let's say I have tables of Users, and Items.

```
User
----------
id
userName

Item
----------
id
itemName
cost
```

Then, to implement a solution for finding out items that a user already owns versus items that a user wants, I create these two other tables with foreign keys

```
User_ItemOwned
----------
id
userId (fk)
itemId (fk)

User_ItemWishlist
----------
id
userId (fk)
itemId (fk)
```

Ostensibly, these tables appear to be the same aside from the name of the tables. This strikes me as odd and brings me to the question- Is it inherently problematic from a database design perspective to have two database tables that store the same data types but are categorically different based purely on the title of the table? Would a more effective design be to have a single User_Item table that had a category for the state (Wishlist or Owned)?

Comment: What's wrong with that? Each table may evolve in different ways over time. You could always have a field like "list_type" that's either `owned` or `wishlist` but this also works.

Comment: I was asking largely because I couldn't put my finger on what I find wrong with this design, but as Vikdor points out below having a new table for every state category scales poorly if the number of states a User_Item can be in increases. However, you make a good point and I do think there is some benefit in allowing the flexibility for tables to evolve over time and capture data that may be specific to a category. Perhaps this is just an instance of pros and cons with respect to the amount of repeated work (multiple User_Item style tables) vs flexibility

Comment: This is one of those "it really depends" type questions. If wishlist evolves in a way where you have more than one wishlist, if "owned" has other properties too, then these tables will diverge. If they're either in or out, then this is really a generic "add item to list" table where lists are "owned" and "wishlist". You'll have to think about what these features do, and how they're likely to evolve as your business requirements expand over time.

Answer (score 1):

The state of the item (owned/wishlist) w.r.t to the user appears to be an attribute of the user-item relationship. So, the data in two tables should be stored in a single one, with state as another column.
Moreover, if there are going to be more such states in future, it would simply be additional values allowed in the state column.

If you really want to have separate table names (motivation is not clear from the question), you can create views on top of the table with appropriate filters. HTH.

Comment: I appreciate the insight, and I think it perhaps comes down to a question of simplicity (a single category) vs flexibility (being able to add additional data specific to certain types of user-item relationships). I think the "smell" I was dealing with was the apparent repetition, but that does not seem inherently wrong to do.

Comment: If there are additional attributes, specific to each category, there are multiple ways to model such a relationship. For example, you can view the categories from inheritance point of view and use Table-per-concrete-class model where all the common attributes are in a common table and attributes specific to each category are stored in separate tables. @WhatsInAName